# route for showing the category name in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am a novice in rails development.I need help regarding the routes i have to write in my application.I have the following models: Categories, ItemTypes and Items.
One category can have many itemtypes which in turn can have many items.

I need to write routes  similar to this:

**www.domain.com**
-home screen.In home screen i'll show list of categories

when a category gets clicked i should show all the items falling under that category
i.e.,the items of all the itemtypes of that category and url should be like

**www.domain.com/category-name**

the item listing page will have dropdown for item types..from which the user can filter the items when the user selects a item type the url should be like

**www.domain.com/category-name/item-type-name/items**

Please help me on writing the routes for these cases.Btw the below are my models i've written

```
   class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :item_types
     has_many :items, :through => :item_types, :source => :category

     attr_accessible :name, :enabled, :icon
   end

  class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :category
        has_many :items
  end
  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to:item_type
  end
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in routes.rb:

```
# Run rake routes after modifying to see the names of the routes that are generated.
resources :categories, :path => "/", :only => [:index, :show] do
  resources :item_types, :path => "/", :only => [:index, :show] do
    resources :items, :path => "/", :only => [:index, :show, :new]
  end
end
```

Then, in your category.rb model:

```
def to_param # Note that this will override the [:id] parameter in routes.rb.
  name
end
```

In your categories_controller.rb:

```
def show
  Category.find_by_name(params[:id]) # to_param passes the name as params[:id]
end
```

In your item_type.rb model:

```
def to_param # Note that this will override the [:id] parameter in routes.rb.
  name
end
```

In your item_types_controller.rb:

```
def show
  ItemType.find_by_name(params[:id]) # to_param passes the name as params[:id]
end
```

I would recommend adding before_saves and validations to your models to ensure that the names are HTML-safe, something along the lines of `name = name.downcase.gsub(" ", "-")`should get you started with a before_save (but it is by no means comprehensive).

Comment: thanks @niiru for your quick reply.i did exactly the same what you said in your answer.The resulting urls are like                     domain.com/categories/Entertainment...                              domain.com/categories/Entertainment/item_types/Events...           I want to remove the categories and item_types from the urls...I jst want them to appear as below       domain.com/Entertainment.....domain.com/Entertainment/Events..

Comment: the `:path => "/"` option on the resources declarations should remove "categories", "item_types" from your routes. I originally included it on the :categories line, but forgot it on the :item_types and :items lines.

Comment: thanks again @niiru..this worked like a charm..can i include the constraints on these routes like this                                                       resources :categories, :path => "/", :only => [:show,:index] do
   resources :business_types,:path => "/", :only => [:show, :index] do
     resources :businesses,:path => "/", :only => [:show, :index, :new]
   end
  end

Comment: Yes, that will work. I added it into the answer as well. Note that you may want to have :create in there as well if you've got :new.